# I'm having trouble with my 2006 ba Falcon not getting any power to the ignition

Tags: ford, ignition-switch, falcon

I've had to put a new ignition switch and barrel in due to the other one faulting I've put it all back together but now when I turn the key there's nothing no dash lights and not starting I'm in need of some advice please

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Did you disconnect the battery before you replaced the switch? If not, did you notice any sparks? You may have blown a fuse or the fusible link if your car has one. The fusible link would be found in one of the not-so-thick wires attached to the + terminal of the battery.